# Does awaiting a non-async method that returns Task<TResult> release a thread back to the thread pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I'm still figuring out how the async/await works in C#.

If I have a .NET web API application with the following method in my Controller.cs:

```
[HttpGet("Foo1")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Foo1()
{
    return await Foo2();
}
```

And the following Foo2() function:

```
public Task<int> Foo2()

    int a;
    //do some work with a that takes a long time
    return Task.FromResult(a);

}
```

When I receive an HTTP request for the Foo1 method. Does the
`return await Foo2();` inside the Controller.cs release the thread until the whole Foo2() function is completed, and is this the correct way of using await/async inside the Web API?

Comment: As written, it's going to be a `StackOverflowException` because you're recursively calling `Foo1`.

Comment: `is this the correct way of using await/async inside the Web API?` - No. The normal way to make a controller action asynchronous is to start at the lowest-level API (e.g., db access or a webapi call) and make that asynchronous first, and then to allow `async`/`await` to grow from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in case if `Foo2` is "truly" async and no in your current case (assuming `Foo1` actually calls `Foo2` and not itself) - state machine implemented by compiler will not actually "await" a finished task and will continue synchronous execution.

Also check out great [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) article by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: What would make a function a "truly" async function?

Comment: @KerimNurikic a truly asynchronous operation is one that `Foo2().IsCompleted == false`. The `Task` should represent an ongoing operation, not an already completed operation.

Answer (score 2):

First I'm going to assume you meant to call `Foo2`, not `Foo1`, as the latter results in a stack overflow from infinite recursion.

> release the thread until the whole Foo2() function is completed

Every time someone mentions threads in relation to tasks, it raises the hair on the back of my neck. There's literally no thread switching in your code, async or not. And in general tasks have nothing to do with threads.

As to your question, in your example `Foo2` isn't going to be generated as an async function but as a normal synchronous function. You'll get regular old imperative code as if there were no async code involved at all.

Comment: Probably worth explaining *why* it's going to be synchronous

Comment: Because there's no awaiting of a non-completed task. Going down the await tree, every single `await` is on a completed awaitable, which is treated as synchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo2()` does not look like a real async task method its return `Task.FromResult(a);` faking the task. so answer is just returning by using  `Task.FromResult(a);` and awaiting a method which does not do anything asynchronous does not make any sense. also please note async programing is not a multithreading programing.